# SSRS - Not understanding how to do certain grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Can anyone explain how to do the grouping below? I am not able to figure out how this type of grouping was achieve in SSRS. The closest I found was this example https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6533/multiple-row-grouping-levels-in-ssrs-report/. But the grouping lines are reversed?

Grouping Reverse?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cryK.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find is easier to start with your details row, include just the fields that you want at the lowest (Detail) level. Based on your example this would your `Fruit` and `Test` fields.

Once that's done, right-click the "Details" rowgroup under main design window and then add a parent group for the first group, in your case `TypeOfFruit`, repeat this process for `CountryOfOrigin` and `Company`.

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I can't upvote since the account is new but I marked it as answered.